# how put result of a select query to a function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function named `get_open_profit` that calculated some data.

input of this function does not work properly.

I have a table named `results` that if we querying on it the result is :

`select sum_buy_trades from results order by sum_buy_trades limit 1` : 274

`select total_avg_buy from results order by sum_buy_trades limit 1` : 2019746

when I write function like this

`select get_open_profit(274, 2019746)` result is : 30192700

But if write like this I got error

`select get_open_profit(select sum_buy_trades from results order by sum_buy_trades limit 1, select total_avg_buy from results order by sum_buy_trades limit 1`

why it does not worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use scalar subqueries (that is, subqueries that return one value), then each needs their own parentheses:

```
select get_open_profit( (select sum_buy_trades
                         from results
                         order by sum_buy_trades
                         limit 1
                        ),
                        (select total_avg_buy
                         from results
                         order by sum_buy_trades
                         limit 1
                        )
                       );
```

In this case, though, the query might be more naturally written as:

```
select get_open_profit( r.sum_buy_trades, r.total_avg_buy )
from (select sum_buy_trades, total_avg_buy
      from results
      order by sum_buy_trades
      limit 1
     ) r;
```